# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deploy'

Tags: python, account, brownie

from brownie import network, config, accounts
from brownie import FundMe

```
def deploy_fund_me():
  account = get_account
  fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account})
  print(f"contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")  

def main():
  deploy_fund_me()
```

Comment: Evidently `FundMe` is a function and has no `deploy` attribute, so `FundMe.deploy(...)` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the limited traceback I would have to assume that get_account is supposed to return an object that can be used by the FundMe.deploy function. If this is the case then the line `account = get_account` should actually be `account = get_account()`, which will actually call the function `get_account` instead of passing a reference to it.

If this is not the problem then please edit your question to provide a full traceback so we can see more clearly what is causing the problem.